# can an azure web site be a single index.html file?

Tags: deployment, azure-web-app-service

can an azure web site be a single index.html file?

I keep getting **The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.**

and when I look at wwwroot my that file keeps disappearing.

I'm deploy using ftp-simple through visual studio code into /site/wwwroot/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, an Azure Web App can be a single index.html. Try creating a clean new site, and dropping an index.html in `d:\home\site\wwwroot` via [Kudu Console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) (or FTP), and you will be able to request it.

Comment: This helps but I think there is more to it.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47877650/how-do-i-host-a-public-static-site-as-a-web-app